# Create dynamic members of PSObject

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

This is what I got:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$objectCollection = @()
$groups = (Get-ADGroup -Filter *)

foreach ($group in $groups) {
    $groupName = ($group.SamAccountName)

    $object = (New-Object –Type PSObject)
    Add-Member -InputObject $object -MemberType NoteProperty –Name ($groupName) –Value ""

    $groupMembers = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "$groupName" -Recursive |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)
    $object.$groupName = $groupMembers

    $objectCollection += $object
}

$objectCollection | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\test.csv `
    -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

The goal with this script is to create a CSV file where the AD group name is the header in one column an then all the members of the group listed below on separate lines. Next group is in a new column with the AD-group name as header and so on...

Normally I create as many Members as I need but this time I want it to be dynamic to how many groups there is and the script above only displays the first group in the $groups array.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the script to export Groups and nested objects differently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33649558/change-the-script-to-export-groups-and-nested-objects-differently)

Answer (score 0):

Having each group on a separate column in a CSV file seems illogical to me ; one on each row would IMHO be better (and easier too).

Here is how I would do it:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-ADGroup -Filter * | ForEach-Object {

    [PSCustomObject]@{    
        Name = $_.samAccountName
        Members = (Get-ADGroupMember $_ -Recursive | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) -join ","
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\test.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

Output:

```
"Name";"Members"
"Administrators";"Administrator,..."
"Domain Users";"Administrator,TestUser,..."
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer soda. This works great and will do it for me but it would be nice to be able to do it as I mention above aswell (one column per group) if that's possible. Cheers

Comment: May I know what this file will be used for ? I can help to make an Excel spreadsheet with the format you need, but it would be too complicated with a CSV file (in my opinion).

Comment: This is for a migration from an existing AD-domain (DC) to a new one and since there is alot of "trash-groups" and other information that is no longer useful I don't want to do a 1-to-1 replication. I thought that a csv-file with all users+groups separated by column would be easier to import to the new domain (DC) (just delete the columns I no longer want) but I may be wrong.

Comment: So your question is basically : what is the best way to transfer a list of AD groups and all their members from one domain to another ? Btw, check the comment on your question, the linked question provides a snippet to transpose the data in columns. But I wonder what you will do with it next ^_^.