# Create list headers and combine

Tags: powershell

I want to create a bunch of lists, with a header where the list members are dynamic in size.

Then I want to combine the lists to make an array, or csv for export.

I've tried

```
$a = new-object psobject
$a | add-member ...
```

However the value on this does not accept variables of 'system.array' type,the objects show up as one continuous string, not two objects on separate lines.

I've tried :

```
$a = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
$a.add()
```

but I can't create a header with this list.

Here's a sample of what i want the final product to look like

```
col1     col2     col3
admin    karl     john
jake     rupert   pinko
drumpf            deckard
```

where the names of the columns are pulled from different servers in the domain, and will have a dynamic length every time i run the script - then i want to export it as a csv.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide a simple sample of what you want to do ?

Comment: `Transpose-Data col1, col2, col3 ('admin', 'jake', 'drumpf'), ('karl', 'rupert'), ('john', 'pinko', 'deckard')` http://stackoverflow.com/a/33650945

Comment: Thanks for the info - but that's not working because the list is dynamic - and when i feed transpose-data a variable of system.array type - it lists the items as one long string, instead of on separate lines. So it's the same problem i had before.

Comment: *but that's not working because the list is dynamic* It is not a problem at all. See linked question, here OP also have dynamic lists, but my code work for her/him. BTW, if you want to notify someone of your comment, then you should use @JustinBeagley notation.

Comment: So i've tried that function with my lists... and i don't konw what i'm doing wrong, but it's failing. So i have a $var1 which is a system.array type, with admin, john as the two objects. and a $var2 which is a system.array type with admin, kyle, peter as the three objects - when i add your function, and then type: tranpose-data $var1 $var2 | export-csv -path .. that file is blank. @PetSerAl

Comment: @JustinBeagley `Transpose-Data col1, col2 $var1, $var2`

Comment: @PetSerAl that was it - i wasn't inputting the data after the cmdlet correctly - thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

try Something like this

```
#solution 1
$yourlist=@()
$yourlist+=[pscustomobject]@{Header1="Val1.1";Header2=Get-Date;Header3=15}
$yourlist+=[pscustomobject]@{Header1="Val1.2";Header2=(Get-Date).AddDays(1);Header3=30}
$yourlist

#solution 2
$yourlist=@()
$yourlist+=New-Object -TypeName "psobject" -Property  @{Header1="Val2.1";Header2=Get-Date;Header3=15}
$yourlist+=New-Object -TypeName "psobject" -Property  @{Header1="Val2.2";Header2=(Get-Date).AddDays(1);Header3=30}
$yourlist

#solution 3
$yourlist = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
$yourlist.add((New-Object -TypeName "psobject" -Property  @{Header1="Val3.1";Header2=Get-Date;Header3=15}))
$yourlist.add((New-Object -TypeName "psobject" -Property  @{Header1="Val3.2";Header2=(Get-Date).AddDays(1);Header3=30}))
$yourlist

#solution 4
$element1 = new-object psobject
$element1 | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Header1" -Value "Val4.1" 
$element1 | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Header2" -Value (Get-Date) 
$element1 | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Header3" -Value 15

$element2 = new-object psobject
$element2 | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Header1" -Value "Val4.2" 
$element2 | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Header2" -Value (Get-Date).AddDays(1) 
$element2 | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Header3" -Value 30 

$yourlist=@()
$yourlist+=$element1
$yourlist+=$element2
$yourlist
```

Comment: that doesn't work with a dynamic variable of type system.array put into the -value parameter. Unless you're asking me to place every object in the array into it's own separate variable - which isn't an acceptable approach. And separating the objects using a foreach-loop fails as well, because the 'name' parameter errors out in the add-member command, as the name already exists.

Comment: this examples work correctly on my pc and satisty your ask and example. If you list of columns is dynamic, you can use solution 4, but you must readapt my code and not doubt loop on you array....