# How to arrange values of different arrays in a tabular form?

Tags: powershell, dataformat

I have three arrays such as Sender, Recipient and Subject; I need to arrange them in tabular form as below.

```
Sender              Recipient             Subject
xxxx@xxx.com        xxx@xxx.com           xxx
```

Here is my code

```
dir|ForEach-Object { 
  $Name=$_.Name 
  foreach ($N in $Name) { Import-Csv $N|` 
    Foreach { 
      $Sender+=$_.SenderAddress 
      $Recipient+=$_.RecipientAddress 
      $Subject+=$_.Subject 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Can anyone look into this?

Regards,
Kiran

Comment: please add the programming language tag, and a sample of what you have tried

Comment: Can you give us a code example of these arrays?
How can we match the these 3 arrays or are they in the correct order like: $Sender[0], $Recipient[0], $Subject[0] ?

Comment: PS C:\Users\Public\Documents\Phishing> dir|ForEach-Object {
$Name=$_.Name
foreach ($N in $Name) {
Import-Csv $N|`
Foreach {
$Sender+=$_.SenderAddress
$Recipient+=$_.RecipientAddress
$Subject+=$_.Subject
}
}
}

Comment: `Transpose-Data Sender, Recipient, Subject $Sender, $Recipient, $Subject`. [`Transpose-Data`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33650945)

Comment: Import-Csv command shows the data in tabular form; What if there isn't any CSV file but only arrays? How should I arrange the values of several arrays in a tabular form with their array names as header?

Comment: I get the below error for Transpose-Data  Transpose-Data : The term 'Transpose-Data' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:12 char:1
+ Transpose-Data Sender, Recipient, Subject $Sender, $Recipient, $Subje ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Transpose-Data:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple perfectly aligned arrays, you can easily zip them together with a `for` loop:

```
$Sender = @('jack@company.example','jill@company.example')
$Recipient = @('alice@company.example','bob@company.example')
$Subject = @('Overdue invoices','Receipts')

$mailObjects = for($i = 0; $i -lt $Sender.Count; $i++){
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Sender = $Sender[$i]
        Recipient = $Recipient[$i]
        Subject = $Subject[$i]
    }
}
```

Now you can use `Format-Table`:

```
PS C:\> $mailObjects |Format-Table
Sender               Recipient             Subject
------               ---------             -------
jack@company.example alice@company.example Overdue invoices
jill@company.example bob@company.example   Receipts
```

Comment: Import|ForEach-Object {
Search-Mailbox -identity "$_.RecipientAddress" -SearchQuery "From:$_.SenderAddress","Subject:$_.Subject" -targetmailbox "XXXXX" -targetfolder "Test" -deletecontent -Force -loglevel full -WhatIf
}

Comment: Now, I have another problem; The above script isn't working; Import is a function I have created to import CSV file. It runs but gives me below error.

Comment: @LittleBuddha Please describe the actual problem you're trying to solve. Doesn't sound like output formatting is you're actual issue

Comment: The operation couldn't be performed because object '@{SenderAddress=XXX@gmail.com; 
RecipientAddress=XXXX@company.com; Subject=Test 10}.RecipientAddress' couldn't be found on 
'XXXXXXX.XXXXXXXX.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (0:Int32) [Search-Mailbox], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=XXXXXXX,RequestId=XXXXXX,TimeStamp=XXXXX X:XX 
   :XX PM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ManagementObjectNotFoundException] 3B2653F3,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Tasks.SearchM  
  ailbox
    + PSComputerName        : ps.outlook.com

Comment: Mathias, arranging arrays in tabular wasn't the main problem; I have a bunch of CSV files which have Sender Addresses, Recipient Addresses and Subject lines; I need to remove them from mailboxes. I'm trying to assign the strings using $_.XXX; I just want to know whether foreach loop assigning the values right.

Comment: @LittleBuddha By now you should have discovered that posting multi line code in comments is a bad idea. [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46140255/edit) your question to contain additional information.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I have no clue how to use the site; I will figure it out, I promise. Please bear with me :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting your code right, you are referring to columns of csv files not arrays. A select of the wished properties should suffice after importing, the new shorter property names could be achieved with a `[pscustomobject]`.

Suppose there are:

```
> Get-Content first.csv
"othercol","SenderAddress","RecipientAddress","Subject"
"","jack@company.example","alice@company.example","Overdue invoices"
"","jill@company.example","bob@company.example","Receipts"
```

and:

```
>Get-Content second.csv:
"SenderAddress","RecipientAddress","Subject","othercol"
"john@company.example","anna@company.example","Overdue deliveries","xyz"
"jim@company.example","willb@company.example","Orders","abc"
```

This one liner:

```
foreach ($File in (gci *.csv)){Import-Csv $File|Select SenderAddress,Recipientaddress,Subject}
```

will output:

```
SenderAddress        RecipientAddress      Subject
-------------        ----------------      -------
jack@company.example alice@company.example Overdue invoices
jill@company.example bob@company.example   Receipts
john@company.example anna@company.example  Overdue deliveries
jim@company.example  willb@company.example Orders
```

This more verbose version:

```
ForEach ($File in (Get-ChildItem *.csv)){
    Import-Csv $File | Select-Object SenderAddress,Recipientaddress,Subject |
        ForEach-Object{[pscustomobject] @{Sender    = $_.SenderAddress
                                          Recipient = $_.Recipientaddress
                                          Subject   = $_.Subject}
        }
}
```

yields this output:

```
Sender               Recipient             Subject
------               ---------             -------
jack@company.example alice@company.example Overdue invoices
jill@company.example bob@company.example   Receipts
john@company.example anna@company.example  Overdue deliveries
jim@company.example  willb@company.example Orders
```